# custom facebook like link?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is it possible to add a custom facebook like icon? I would like it to be part of an `<ul>` and I don't really want to load another library their SDK or all the `<meta>` tags....

Has anyone implemented a custom like button? I don't need the counter etc that their buttons provide, and to be honest, they are ugly. I have been searching around for the last 2 hours with no real luck.

I found this:

```
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

But it implements one of their buttons.

**EDIT:**

I have read their API, while very easy to use I don't like the buttons generated from their `<iframe>` or XFBML code. I am simply looking to find out if there is a way to make a custom link from something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="some code here">Facebook</a></li>
</ul>
```

Am I missing something in their API? it always generates a HUGE button with a counter and their graphics, which is exactly what I don't want.

---

Comment: What is this in the context of? A facebook app or another web app?

Comment: Its just in the navigation of my website. I simply want a link that says "facebook" that when clicked will add the content to the persons wall. Same as what happens when you use one of fb's "like buttons"

Comment: You realize you need to use the facebook APIs for that right? Which means using their scripts. Which means that code is the best you can do.

Comment: @drachenstern - apparently I need to edit my question

Comment: Standing by to see the updated one. You also need to revisit your accepted answer ratio. You've been around here long enough to get how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not hand crafting it, there's the [Facebook developer "Like" API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

If their API doesn't expose what the generated buttons do for you to copy, one way to find out what the like button is actually doing (if it's not a hyperlink, and since it might be posting by ajax, this could happen) is finding out how the event is handled in javascript. This may be problematic if the script has been optimised/minified.

Another approach is to find out what HTTP requests it generates, using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to listen to the request and inspect it to see its target and any form data.

If you're happy with the functionality of the like button, but not its style, restyle it with CSS, this may be the safer option, as any API change may break any mimicked script.

Otherwise, unless you're designing your own icons, you can download the free [silk icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/), use the thumb up icon as an image, and slightly edit it for any mouse-over/click events that require different icons, and you can handle the events with JavaScript, [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [JQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/) (depending on which libraries you've already got loaded).

That should deal with the UI behaviour, any calls back to the server could be made with AJAX ([JQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

Comment: the icons aren't an issue, I just want it to be an html link inside the ul. I was asking more about the code that makes the page "liked" on someones fb acct

Comment: I'm guessing, you've used their API documentation: on Like: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Comment: @StuperUser - I must not be communicating very well today. I don't like the buttons their API provides, the style or the counter next to them. I just need to figure out the code I can add to an <ul><li><a href="URL/CODE HERE TO ADD MY PAGE">facebook</a></li></ul>

Comment: Most probably my fault, I've not used the Facebook API before, and usually program on the server too, so I'm probably asking less than useful questions. One way to find out what the like button is actually doing if it's not a hyperlink (since it might be posting by ajax, this is likely) is finding out how the event is handled in javascript, which may be problematic if the script has been optimised/minified. Another approach is to find out what HTTP requests it generates,using http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to listen to the request and inspect it to see its target and any form data.

Comment: @StuperUser - thanks, I was actually just checking it via FF's net console. I think I can mimic it in some way

Comment: Excellent. That will get it to do what you want, but in terms of maintainability it may be safer to restyle the button, as if they update the API for whatever reason, your mimicked code may break.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this because their button isn't keyboard or screen reader accessible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't change the CSS because everything is contained in an iframe on the facebook domain (you can't modify the dom of an iframe if it is not on the same domain). I would love to be proven wrong though.

Answer (score 18):

I found from another post here:

```
<a title="send to Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT" target="_blank"><span><img width="14" height="14" src="'icons/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" /> Facebook></a>
```

I used this and works well:)

Comment: This looks good. One question, how do you pass in the image exactly? a url doesn't seem to work, and it doesn't pick up on og:image.

Comment: This is great to "share" things, but is there any similar URL you can use to *like* a Facebook page?

Comment: @tiltos, according to [this site](http://www.port11.de/blog/facebook-sharerphp-nutzen) the target page should have a tag like this `<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg"   href="http://example.com/picture.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 6):

Customizing the Like button is [against Facebook's policies](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php).

"While you may scale the size to suit your needs, you may not modify the Like Button in any other way (such as by changing the design)."

Answer (score 1):

I found Chaddo's article on [Custom Facebook Like Button (BlackHat Button)](http://www.chaddo.com/index.php/custom-facebook-like-button/) very effective using CSS to customize the button.  You can download the [zip source code](http://arborsupport.com/warriorBlackHat/likebuttons.zip). It works well, and could use improvement in regards to height.