# Using the LIKE Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I want to add the Facebook LIKE button to a page on a website. There are a couple of points:-

1. The webpage has an image background so I want the background to the
   LIKE button to be transparent. The basic tool on face book to create
   the button only allows a dark or light background. How can I change
   that?
2. The webpage has a number of news items and I want to use the LIKE
   button after each news item  so only that item appears on the users
   FB page. Am I simply able to adjust the URL in the code  that the FB
   tool returns?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596068/custom-facebook-like-link/

Answer (score 0):

The "Like" button has limited options for styling according to this thread:

[Custom skin for facebook like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493117/custom-skin-for-facebook-like-button)

This will achieve what you are trying to do using a "Share" button:

```
<a type="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://mywebsite.com">
<img style="cursor:pointer" src="/images/customfacebookpic.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: FYI, sharer.php is being deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Styling of the like button was intentionally removed by Facebook and they give us limited availability to change it (just lite/dark). See this post: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=236534

And if you use the way back machine, you can see how you used to be able to style the button by adding the css parameter.